# building a Live location sharing using MERN stack

Tags: web, geolocation, mern

i want to build a react app to share the my location with my friends and family but i dont have any idea how to implement this in the proejct
i researched a lot but havent found any resource over it
my idea is to build an web application which can be used to eachothers location in a group it would be helpfull for going on a long drive with multiple vehicles

i researched over multiple articles and get an idea to implement maps in the react app
but i want to know how to show the live location on the map